# R calculate median and last row in groups for certain rows

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm working with grouping and median, I'd like to have a grouping of a `data.frame` with the median of certain rows (not all) and the last value.

My data are something like this:

```
 test <- data.frame(
id = c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'),
value = c(1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,1,8,3,4,2,9))
> test
   id value
1   A     1
2   A     2
3   A     3
4   A     4
5   A     5
6   B     3
7   B     4
8   B     5
9   B     1
10  B     8
11  C     3
12  C     4
13  C     2
14  C     9
```

For each `id`, I need the median of the three (number may vary, in this case three) central rows, then the last value.

I've tried first of all with only one `id`.

```
test_a <- test[which(test$id == 'A'),]
> test_a
  id value
1  A     1
2  A     2
3  A     3
4  A     4
5  A     5
```

The desired output is this for this one, 
Having this:

```
median(test_a[(nrow(test_a)-3):(nrow(test_a)-1),]$value) # median of three central values
tail(test_a,1)$value                                     # last value
```

I used this:

```
library(tidyverse)

test_a %>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(m = median(test_a[(nrow(test_a)-3):(nrow(test_a)-1),]$value),
            last = tail(test_a,1)$value) %>%
  data.frame()
  id m last
1  A 3    5
```

But when I tried to generalize to all id:

```
test %>% group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(m = median(test[(nrow(test)-3):(nrow(test)-1),]$value),
             last = tail(test,1)$value) %>%
   data.frame()
  id m last
1  A 3    9
2  B 3    9
3  C 3    9
```

I think that the formulas take the full dataset to calculate last value and median, but I cannot imagine how to make it works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your groups always have 5 rows?

Comment: No, I'll update the question, it is not enough general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
test %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(m = median(value[(length(value)-3):(length(value)-1)]),
            last = value[length(value)])

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      id     m  last
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
1      A     3     5
2      B     4     8
3      C     4     9
```

You just refer to variable `value` instead of the whole dataset within `summarise`.

---

Edit: Here's a generalized version.

```
test %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(m = ifelse(length(value) == 1, value, 
                       ifelse(length(value) == 2, median(value), 
                              median(value[(ceiling(length(value)/2)-1):(ceiling(length(value)/2)+1)])),
            last = value[length(value)])
```

If a group has only one row, the value itself will be stored in `m`. If it has only two rows, the `median` of these two rows will be stored in `m`. If it has three or more rows, the middle three rows will be chosen dynamically and the `median` of those will be stored in `m`.

Comment: Very nice, it works: I've tried also with my real data, but there are some id with only one row, so there is this error: `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts.` How do you advice me to manage this?

Comment: I've tried this for the median  when the length is < 4 `ifelse(length(value)<4,9999,median(value[(length(value)-3):(length(value)-1)]))`, is it correct in your opinion?